# Turn dataframe with a row for each id and law (with begin and end years) into a file with a row for each id and year

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df called `laws` with a row for each law (one for each id):

```
laws <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),beginyear=c(2001,2002,2005),endyear=c(2003,2005,2006), law1=c(0,0,1), law2=c(1,0,1))
```

from which I want to create second called `idyear` with a row for each id and year:

```
idyear <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6)), year=(rep(c(2001:2006),3)), law1=c(rep(0,16),1,1), law2=c(1,1,1,rep(0,13),1,1))
```

How would I efficiently go about writing some code to get the `idyear` df output from the `laws` df? The two law variables are indicator variables == 1 if the `idyear$year` is >= `laws$beginyear` AND `idyear$year` is <= `laws$endyear`.

I am a beginner with R, but I'm willing to try anything (apply, loops, etc.) to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). The last `as.data.frame()` is optional, which just convert the `tbl` to a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

idyear <- laws %>%
  mutate(year = map2(beginyear, endyear, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  complete(id, year = full_seq(year, period = 1L), fill = list(law1 = 0L, law2 = 0L)) %>%
  select(-beginyear, -endyear) %>%
  as.data.frame()
idyear
#    id year law1 law2
# 1   1 2001    0    1
# 2   1 2002    0    1
# 3   1 2003    0    1
# 4   1 2004    0    0
# 5   1 2005    0    0
# 6   1 2006    0    0
# 7   2 2001    0    0
# 8   2 2002    0    0
# 9   2 2003    0    0
# 10  2 2004    0    0
# 11  2 2005    0    0
# 12  2 2006    0    0
# 13  3 2001    0    0
# 14  3 2002    0    0
# 15  3 2003    0    0
# 16  3 2004    0    0
# 17  3 2005    1    1
# 18  3 2006    1    1
```

Comment: Very slick! Thanks for showing me `map2`- I could not sort out how to build all the sequential years with `mutate`.

Answer (score 4):

**1) base** `expand.grid` will create an 18 x 2 data frame of all `id` and `year` combinations and then `merge` will merge it back together with `laws`.  Zero out any `law1` and `law2` entry for which `year` is not between `beginyear` and `endyear`.  Finally drop the `beginyear` and `endyear` columns.  No packages are used.

```
g <- with(laws, expand.grid(year = min(beginyear):max(endyear), id = id))
m <- merge(g, laws)
m[m$year < m$beginyear | m$year > m$endyear, c("law1", "law2")] <- 0
m <- subset(m, select = - c(beginyear, endyear))

# check
identical(m, idyear)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) magrittr** This is the same solution as (1) except we have used magrittr pipelines to express it.  Note the mixture of pipe operators.

```
library(magrittr)

laws %$%
     expand.grid(year = min(beginyear):max(endyear), id = id) %>%
     merge(laws) %$%
     { .[year < beginyear | year > endyear, c("law1", "law2")] <- 0; .} %>%
     subset(select = - c(beginyear, endyear))
```

**Update:** Fixed. Added (2).

Comment: I thought it might be a merge as well, but that result is not what was requested. The merge function doesn't fill in between ranges. Maybe some of your sqldf magic could succeed.

Comment: Yes, but the OP also offers a construction of what he is seeking and your answer is not that.

Comment: OK .Have fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `mapply` function can help.

```
# Function to expand year between begin and end
gen_data <- function(x_id, x_beginyear, x_endyear, x_law1, x_law2){
  df <- data.frame(x_id, x_beginyear:x_endyear, x_law1, x_law2)
  df
}

idyearlst <- data.frame()

idyearlst <- rbind(idyearlst, mapply(gen_data, laws$id, laws$beginyear,
 laws$endyear, laws$law1, laws$law2))

# Finally convert list to data.frame
idyear <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, idyearlst), c("id", "year", "law1", "law2"))

Result will be like:
> idyear
     id year law1 law2
V1.1  1 2001    0    1
V1.2  1 2002    0    1
V1.3  1 2003    0    1
V2.4  2 2002    0    0
V2.5  2 2003    0    0
V2.6  2 2004    0    0
V2.7  2 2005    0    0
V3.8  3 2005    1    1
V3.9  3 2006    1    1
```

Comment: Best answer so far. Actually answers the question rather than an approximate stab.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of an ugly approach, but I think it gets what you're after, using G. Grothendieck's `g` `expand.grid` data frame as a base, and your `laws` dataframe.

```
new.df <- data.frame(t(apply(g, 1, function(x){
  yearspan = laws[laws$id == x['id'], 'beginyear']:laws[laws$id == x['id'], 'endyear']
  law1 = laws$law1[laws$id == x['id'] & x['year'] %in% yearspan]
  law2 = laws$law2[laws$id == x['id'] & x['year'] %in% yearspan]
  x['law1'] = ifelse(length(law1 > 0), law1, 0)
  x['law2'] = ifelse(length(law2 > 0), law2, 0)
  return(x)
})))

> new.df
   id year law1 law2
1   1 2001    0    1
2   1 2002    0    1
3   1 2003    0    1
4   1 2004    0    0
5   1 2005    0    0
6   1 2006    0    0
7   2 2001    0    0
8   2 2002    0    0
9   2 2003    0    0
10  2 2004    0    0
11  2 2005    0    0
12  2 2006    0    0
13  3 2001    0    0
14  3 2002    0    0
15  3 2003    0    0
16  3 2004    0    0
17  3 2005    1    1
18  3 2006    1    1
```

Libraries:

`dplyr` (for `arrange`, not really necessary)

Data:

```
laws <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                   beginyear=c(2001,2002,2005),
                   endyear=c(2003,2005,2006), 
                   law1=c(0,0,1), law2=c(1,0,1))

g <- with(laws, expand.grid(id = id, year = min(beginyear):max(endyear)))
g <- arrange(g, id)
```